# TypeError: _this.Order.orderRow is undefined

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm working with classes and I'm facing some troubles:

The message I get is:

**TypeError: _this.Order.orderRow is undefined**

The exception is generated when I try to push the new row to the orderRow array.

This is the code:

## Order Class

```
export class Order {

    public orderRow?: OrderRow[];
    public rowNumber?: number;

    constructor(values: Object = {}) {
        Object.assign(this, values);
    }

}

export class OrderRow {
    public rowNumber:number;
    public idSaleOrderRow?: number;
    public idCollection?: number;
    public idProduct?: number;
    public txtCollection?: string;
    public txtName?: string;
    public productName?: string;
    public vQty?: number;
    public vQtyFill?: number;
    public vSellPrice?: number;
    public vCustomerPrice?: number;
    public vCustomerPriceFinal?: number;

    constructor(values: Object = {}) {
        Object.assign(this, values);
    }

}
```

## Not working code

```
Order: Order = <Order>{};
...............
...............
let r:OrderRow = {
              rowNumber: newRowNumber,
              idSaleOrderRow: null,
              idCollection: res.result.idCollection,
              idProduct: res.result.idProduct,
              txtCollection: res.result.txtCollection,
              txtName: res.result.txtName,
              productName: res.result.productName,
              vQty: 1,
              vQtyFill: null,
              vSellPrice: res.result.vSellPrice,
              vCustomerPrice: res.result.vSellPrice,
              vCustomerPriceFinal: res.result.vSellPrice
            };

            this.Order.orderRow.push(r);
```

How can I fix it ?

Thanks to support

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are confusing casting an object literal to constructuing a new instance of the `Order` class, you need to call the `Order` constructor with the `new` operator:

```
Order: Order = new Order({});
```

Also the `orderRow` fields should be initialized:

```
export class Order {    
    public orderRow?: OrderRow[] = [];
}
```